# Actionbar optionsmenu persists after switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

The issue I am running into is with the Actionbar Options Menu. When I switch from a fragment that utilizes a custom Options Menu, the icons that are associated with the menu persist to the new fragment view that does not necessarily use that Options Menu.

Another thing that I have found is that when I switch to another fragment from another place in the app, that fragments option menu icon just gets appended to the actionbar right next to the existing menu icon.

SIDE NOTE: I am utilizing the same Options Menu for more than 1 fragment. I am going to try utilizing 2 different option menus.

**Is there a way to clear the options menu? This way it only shows the options menu associated with 1 fragment at a given time.**

This is what it looks like basically for 2 areas of my app that have problems. This is how I have been inflating the options menu, and how I have been switching back to the "starting" fragment after the options menu button is pressed.

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    // inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_cancel, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_cancel:

        changeFragment();

    }
    return true;
}

public void changeFragment() {

    Fragment fragment = new SearchFragmentActivity();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cell_left_in,
            R.anim.cell_right_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.searchDetailsFragment, fragment);
    //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See if you can extract the logic that you need to work in this example

This is similar to what you want to do example
Github code has ...
similar example

http://i2.wp.com/blog.stylingandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/API7_menu.png

similar example:
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/actionbarcompat-part-5/